# flickering of label in unity

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, mouseevent

i have created a scene where the user has to pick up food items form the shelf. But when mouse is brought over a product, the label has a flickering effect at certain orientations. When i move my first person a little here and there, the flickering effect goes away and the display becomes steady. Please help me fix this bug.

Here's the [link](https://vimeo.com/176012214) for the video

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class Coke_bottles : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GUIText textObject;
    public bool showGUI;
    public GameObject[] objects;
    public int i = 0;
    void OnMouseOver()
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(5f, 5f, 5f);
        showGUI = true;
    }

    void OnMouseExit()
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(2.8593f, 3.2275f, 1f);
        showGUI = false;
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.color = Color.white;
        GUIStyle myStyle = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.GetStyle("label"));
        myStyle.fontSize = 20;
        GUI.Label(new Rect(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 100f, 10f), "");
        if (showGUI)
        {
            GUI.Box(new Rect(100, 50, 300f, 100f), "");
            GUI.Label(new Rect(100, 50, 999f, 999f), "You are selecting " + gameObject.name, myStyle);
        }

        if (i == 1)
        {
            GUI.color = Color.green;
            myStyle.fontSize = 15;
            GUI.Label(new Rect(610.3f, 160.56f, 300f, 100f), "Soft Drink Selected");
        }
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        i = 1;
        transform.position = new Vector3(346.457f, 21.78f, 36.715f);
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, -90, 0));
    }
```